# Spring WS and HTTPS?

Tags: spring

I use Spring WS to send a request to web service (DentalXChange).

```
private static final String MESSAGE = <xml request/>

private final WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
public void customSendAndReceive() {
    StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(MESSAGE));
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
    webServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult("https://prelive2.dentalxchange.com/dws/DwsService",
                source, result);
}
```

And here is error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext); nested exception is java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
```

How to solve it. Thanks

Comment: Did you try this : https://www.codenotfound.com/spring-ws-https-client-server-example.html ?